# JavaScript not working in IE and Firefox, works fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, firefox

My navigation bar is using a (badly written I must say if someone can help me write it better by the way) JavaScript code to have it reduce in size when scrolling down.

It works fine in Chrome but doesn't activate in Firefox and IE.

I suspect it is because the height is set in the CSS file, but I have to set it in CSS for it to look right. Although I am most likely wrong.

Here is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#nav-background').data('size','big');
    });
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var $nav = $('#nav-background');

        if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0) {
            if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
                $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                    height:'60px'
                }, 200);
                $("#nav").animate({margin: "17px 0px 0px 0px"}, 200);
                $(".smoothScroll").animate({margin: "17px 0px 0px 0px"}, 200);
            }
        } else {
            if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
                $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                    height:'80px'
                }, 200);
                $("#nav").animate({margin: "27px 0px 0px 0px"}, 200);
                $(".smoothScroll").animate({margin: "27px 0px 0px 0px"}, 200);
            }  
        }
    });
</script>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#nav-background {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 1000;
    height:80px;
}
#nav-bar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    height:100%;
    max-width:1070px;
}
.smoothScroll {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-top:27px;
}
.logo-thin {
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #5B5B5B;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.logo-bold {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #535353;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.logo-thin:hover {
    cursor: url(../img/cursor-black.png) 20 20, move;
}
.logo-bold:hover {
    cursor: url(../img/cursor-black.png) 20 20, move;
}
#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: auto;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    color: #5B5B5B;
    margin-top:27px;
}
#nav .current a {
    color: #49E2D6;
}
#nav a:hover {
    color:#49E2D6;
    cursor: url(../img/cursor-black.png) 20 20, move;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    top:7px;
}
#nav  a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-position: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: inherit;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s;
    -o-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.nav-seperator {
    position:relative;
    top:-4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

And here is the website:

http://www.onepixelroom.com/droninrenovations/

Comment: what if you change $('body').scrollTop() to $(window).scrollTop() ?

Comment: ^^ Ding, ding! Firefox and IE uses the `<html>` element for the scrollbar, so `$('body').scrollTop()` probably always returns zero. Using window should work everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$('body').scrollTop()
```

to

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

This is usually the recomended way to retrieve the scroll position of the window's content (and so the body as well).

Also I'd suggest to put everything inside the

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//
});
```

block. I mean, also the binding of the scroll event to the navbar resize function.

As a side note jQuery allows you to write the above block (with same funcionality) as

```
$(function() {
//
});
```

Comment: Hey, changing that value means then also deisables the effect on chrome. Could the reason be: #nav-background {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 1000;
    **height:80px;**
}

Comment: I don't think so. The value in the CSS for that element is overridden as JavaScript modifies it (that happens when you animate the element with Jquery). See my edit. Hope it helps...

Comment: Could it be conflicting with my other scripts?

Comment: If you've got other scripts adjusting the scroll position, make sure they are all using the same syntax.

Comment: ' <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#nav').onePageNav({
    currentClass: 'current',
    scrollOffset: 0
  });
});
</script> '

Comment: could this be the culprit?

Comment: nope, i tried with all scripts disabled appart from that one, and still doesnt work :(

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, your solution is indeed the right one and works fine, I just forgot to remove the quote marks when I edited it: if ($(window).scrollTop() instead of if ($('window').scrollTop(). Embarrassing :)

Comment: Things that happens to everyone... I took a look at the site. I'd suggest to put all the scripts in a single file and include that file in the main html page. As you go to production is advisable to minify the javascript file with one of the many tools available. BTW: It seem to me it has heavy javascript processing as the browser scrolling is not fluid. If you experience the same you may profile your javascripts with Firefox profiler. It will tell you where the javascript interpreter spends most of its time. It's a long topic to be discussed here but there are plenty of resources on the web.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for (unrelated to the main question), especially the minify thing, I had no idea about. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: minifying is good for obfuscating the code and reducing its size. But normally gives little performance increase over the javascript execution. However I tried the site with Firefox and performs well. So it's a Safari issue the non-smooth scrolling. I have similar issues on a site of mine.